# Turning a JSON file into a nested list

Tags: html, json, list, handlebars.js, mustache

I have the following **JSON** file:

```
    {
    "teams": {
        "bayernMunichFC": {
            "country": "Germany",
            "city": "Munich",
            "name": "Bayern Munich"
        },
        "1860Munich": {
            "country": "Germany",
            "city": "Munich",
            "name": "1860 Munich"
        },
        "borussiaDortmundFC": {
            "country": "Germany",
            "city": "Dortmund",
            "name": "Borussia Dortmund"
        },
        "hibernianFC": {
            "country": "Scotland",
            "city": "Edinburgh",
            "name": "Hibernian FC"
        },
        "heartOfMidlothianFC": {
            "country": "Scotland",
            "city": "Edinburgh",
            "name": "Heart of Midlothian FC"
        },
        "celticFC": {
            "country": "Scotland",
            "city": "Glasgow",
            "name": "Celtic FC"
        },
        "rangersFC": {
            "country": "Scotland",
            "city": "Glasgow",
            "name": "Rangers FC"
        }
    }
}
```

What I want to do is have an nested list in **HTML**, preferably using Mustache, that that will output this in the browser:

> ```
> - Germany
>    - Munich
>      - Bayern Munich
>      - 1860 Munich
>    - Dortmund
>      - Borussia Dortmund
>  - Scotland
>    - Edinburgh
>      - Hibernian FC
>      - Heart of Midlothian FC
>    - Glasgow
>      - Celtic FC
>      - Rangers FC
> ```

I'm struggling to organise the teams into the required structure. Is it possible to do this with the **JSON** formatted in this way or will I need to do some data manipulation? If so, can you offer me any help or advice?

Many thanks!

P.S. The keys eg "bayernMunichFC", "heartOfMidlothianFC" etc; will be used as dataRef tags as each team name will be a link that passed the dataRef attribute to the URL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

okay that was fun, i dont know if it helps but i wrote some code

```
var results {};
var data= YOUR_JSON;

for(var key in data.teams){  

    if(data.teams.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
        if(!(results[data.teams[key].country] instanceof Object)){
            results[data.teams[key].country] = {};
            results[data.teams[key].country][data.teams[key].city] = {};
            results[data.teams[key].country][data.teams[key].city][key] = data.teams[key].name;    
        }else {
            if(!(results[data.teams[key].country][data.teams[key].city] instanceof Object)){
                results[data.teams[key].country][data.teams[key].city] = {};
                results[data.teams[key].country][data.teams[key].city][key] = data.teams[key].name;  
            }else{
                results[data.teams[key].country][data.teams[key].city][key] = data.teams[key].name;  
            }
        }
    }  
}
```

console.log(results)

which will transform your json to this output:

```
Germany: Object
  Dortmund: Array[1]
    0: "Borussia Dortmund"
  Munich: Array[2]
    0: "Bayern Munich"
    1: "1860 Munich"

Scotland: Object
  Edinburgh: Array[2]
    0: "Hibernian FC"
    1: "Heart of Midlothian FC"

  Glasgow: Array[2]
    0: "Celtic FC"
    1: "Rangers FC"
```

aint that nice, its your expected order and cant be too different from here

if you want to generate a list you can do it like :

```
var html  = "<ul>";

for(var key in results){
    html += "<li>"+key+"</li><ul>";
    for(var akey in results[key]){
        html += "<li>"+akey+"</li><ul>";
        for(var bkey in results[key][akey]){
            html += "<li><a href='"+bkey+"'>"+results[key][akey][bkey]+"</a></li>";
        }
        html += "</ul>";
    }
    html += "</ul>";
}

html += "</ul>"
```

which outputs your desired output :) have fun

```html
<ul><li>Germany</li><ul><li>Munich</li><ul><li><a href='bayernMunichFC'>Bayern Munich</a></li><li><a href='1860Munich'>1860 Munich</a></li></ul><li>Dortmund</li><ul><li><a href='borussiaDortmundFC'>Borussia Dortmund</a></li></ul></ul><li>Scotland</li><ul><li>Edinburgh</li><ul><li><a href='hibernianFC'>Hibernian FC</a></li><li><a href='heartOfMidlothianFC'>Heart of Midlothian FC</a></li></ul><li>Glasgow</li><ul><li><a href='celticFC'>Celtic FC</a></li><li><a href='rangersFC'>Rangers FC</a></li></ul></ul></ul>
```

Comment: Nice! Looks like a step in the right direction. Thank you.

Now I just need to figure out how to get this into an HTML list.

Comment: its not with mustache but i gave you a soultion which generates your desired form of list, if it works for you feel free to upvote and mark as answer